# PHP - DomXPath empty tags

Tags: php, domxpath

I have a html text.

```
$htmlString = '
<span class="title">Random title</span>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore aperiam aut iusto quae error tempore nisi consequuntur natus magni fugiat illum, repellat minima quibusdam aliquam dolor deserunt repudiandae quas, laboriosam.
<div class="title">Title with missing <i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore aperiam aut iusto quae error tempore nisi consequuntur natus magni fugiat illum, repellat minima quibusdam aliquam dolor deserunt repudiandae quas, laboriosam.
';
```

From this html I want every
tag with the 'title' class. So I did this:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($htmlString);

$finder = new DomXPath($document);
$elements = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' title ')]");

foreach($elements as $index => $element) {
    echo $element->ownerDocument->saveXML( $element ) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Its working nicely, but if there is an empty tag 
inside the text it doesn't work properly.

As you can see the empty `<i></i>` tags turned into `</i>`. I need the text with the empty tags. 
So I changed my code to this:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($htmlString);

$finder = new DomXPath($document);
$elements = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' title ')]");

foreach($elements as $index => $element) {
    //echo $element->ownerDocument->saveXML( $element ) . PHP_EOL;
    echo $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $element ) . PHP_EOL; //this is working, but i cant use it becase the php version. im using 5.3.3-7 php version
    //http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php
}
```

and its working. BUT on the server the php version is older than 5.4 so I cant use the saveHTML method like this.

How can I make this ?

BTW the php version that I working on is 5.3.3-7

The full code is here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/23f5629cbd5a4ae031efc5e3c8ca419043b5a158

Comment: And what's the issue that you can't use your method?

Comment: Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php

Comment: The node parameter was added. at 5.3.6 version, i'm working on 5.3.3-7. So i cant pass argument to this method. :(

Comment: When im using the saveHTML method i got this error message: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>19</b><br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($elements as $index => $element) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->appendChild($dom->importNode($element,true));
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
}
```